# How to wait for a value to be reached to continue the method?

Tags: java, swing

```
btnStraight = new JButton("Straight");
    btnStraight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        /* Delay if statement until an ArrayList reaches a certain size */

            if(RouletteHelperMethods.doBet("Straight") == 1){
                textArea.setText("Congrats, you won!");
            } else {
                textArea.setText("Sorry, you lost.");
            }
        }
    });
```

The user is supposed to click on a button, then is told to click on JTextFields to add them to an ArrayList. How do I delay the if statement until this happens?

Comment: More details please -- what do you mean by `"add them to an ArrayList"`? I feel like we're groping in the dark here, that you're withholding too much information from us.

Comment: I edited my question, i am adding JTextFields to an ArrayList, Once the user clicks the button, they should be told to click on JTextFields to add them to ones they want to bet on. Once the ArrayList of JTextFields reaches a certain size, in this case 1, i want to run the if statement.

Comment: Please edit some more. Ask as if we can't see all the code you've not shown, nor understand concepts not fully explained.

Comment: Also show pictures as well, or at least links to images, and we'll edit your post and post the pictures for you.

Comment: Sorry, for the hassle. I took your advice and just rethought how the program runs. It took a few more methods, but it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-think how your program runs since you're coding this as if you have written a linear console program, but that's not the case. Instead you're coding an **event-driven** GUI program, and so instead of having code "wait" you should be reacting to events, and to change in state.

If you need further details on this, please flesh out your question, including giving more about just what your program is supposed to be doing, what ArrayList you mean, and including providing here (and not in a link) a valid [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the link).

I was trying to play with your logical needs, and came up with a small program that creates a bunch of JTextFields. When clicked the text they hold is added to a JTextArea and the fields are added to a selected fields ArrayList. When the number of fields added to the list is 4, then the logic runs. This is called from a FocusListener that is added to all the text fields. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EventDrivenGui extends JPanel {
    private static final int FIELD_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int SELECTED_FIELD_SIZE = 4;
    protected static final Color SELECTED_COLOR = Color.PINK;
    private JButton btnStraight;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
    private List<JTextField> selectedFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

    public EventDrivenGui() {
        btnStraight = new JButton("Straight");
        btnStraight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (selectedFieldList.size() > 0) {
                    return;
                }
                for (JTextField textField : fieldList) {
                    textField.setEnabled(true);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnStraight, "Please Select a text field",
                        "Make Selection", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
        });

        textArea.setFocusable(false);

        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField("Field " + (i + 1), 10);
            field.setEnabled(false); // so they can't select it prematurely
            fieldList.add(field);
            fieldPanel.add(field);

            field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    JTextField tf = (JTextField) e.getComponent();
                    if (!selectedFieldList.contains(tf)) {

                        textArea.append(tf.getText() + "\n");
                        tf.setBackground(SELECTED_COLOR);
                        selectedFieldList.add(tf);
                        if (selectedFieldList.size() >= SELECTED_FIELD_SIZE) {
                            if (RouletteHelperMethods.doBet("Straight") == 1) {
                                textArea.append("Congrats, you won!\n");
                            } else {
                                textArea.append("Sorry, you lost.\n");
                            }

                            reset();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        add(btnStraight);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        add(fieldPanel);
    }

    protected void reset() {
        selectedFieldList.clear();
        for (JTextField jTextField : fieldList) {
            jTextField.setEnabled(false);
            jTextField.setBackground(null);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        EventDrivenGui mainPanel = new EventDrivenGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EventDrivenGui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class RouletteHelperMethods {

    public static int doBet(String bet) {
        return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code, it is nice to see another way to do it. Unfortunately, I just finished my high school java class, and we didn't cover FocusListener.